# Binding to static property in a static class

Tags: wpf, binding

CS :

```
   public static class NavigationManager 
   {  
       public static bool IsSomethingSomething{ get{  return true;}} 
   }
```

Is this Bindable (one way of course) in any way?

Comment: i found to Static property in an instance ..
would you mind posting the link please ?

Comment: I don't have or need a link.

Comment: Are you telling me that you easily found an example of Binding 
to a Static Property of a Static Class ? 
all the examples are of instances which have a Static Property .

Comment: http://controlflow.info/?p=80

Comment: I easily found an example, on SO at that. But that is not what i was trying to say, which is that i have seen it before and that i am not the one who needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"

"{x:Static local:YourClass.YourProperty}"
```

for example :

```
<Button Content="{x:Static local:Constants.ConstantString}" />
```